# How to find out the password of an administrator account from a guest account on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, passwords, user-accounts

I have a computer running Windows 8.1. Currently, I have 2 accounts - an admin and a standard Microsoft account without admin privileges.

From a local account, is there any way of revealing the admin password, say, in plain text?

This is purely on research grounds.

Comment: If you manage to do it, tell Microsoft how and collect a substantial bug bounty.

Comment: Not possible. Simple as that. Even on Linux, where things are less complicated, regular users cannot read `/etc/shadow` to even acquire the encrypted passwords. And even if you could read it, you could only brute force. // Also, this type of question is really off-topic on Super User.

Comment: You can’t.  Administrator accounts cannot determine the password of another account.

Answer (score 1):

Modern passwords are not stored in plaintext anymore. It's a security disaster waiting to happen. What you could potentially retrieve is the stored hash but those are designed not to be reverted to the original text for obvious reasons.

If you need administrator access on a Windows machine you have physical access to, any Windows PE disk will allow you to just reassign the password for any local account. One caveat of this method is that you could potentially bork encrypted files permanently.